# Install wkhtmltopdf on CPanel server without root acces

Tags: bash, cpanel, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to use [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org) on my CPanel server. But I haven't root access and I can't put it in /usr/local/bin or /usr/bin/ .

So I just put the script on my /home/perso/wkhtmltopdf and made a **chmod +x wkhtmltopdf**.

But if I try to execute it, for example like this: **./wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com test.pdf** I get a

> bash: ./wkhtmltopdf: cannot execute binary file

Any idea how can I place my script in order to be able to execute it ?

Answer (score 0):

To run wkhtmltopdf, you need to install on the server.
Try to ask your hosting provider.

Usually for security, providers disable the execution of binary scripts by ordinary users.